# xtensor equivalent of numpy a[a>3] = 1

Tags: numpy, xtensor

Title says it - what is the xtensor equivalent of numpy's

```
# set all elements > 3 to 1
sometensor[sometensor > 3] = 1
```

?

It looks like `xt::filter` works:

```
xt::filter(sometensor, sometensor > 3) = 1
```

But it also looks like the numpy version is much faster. I've build xtensor with xsimd, but it doesn't seem to help in this case. Is there a better, more simd-ish way to do it?

EDIT

I found `filtration`, which indeed is faster (by about 3x), but still slower than numpy (by about 10x)...

SOLUTION (thx Tom!)

```
a = xt::where(a > 0.5, 1.0, a);
```

Is the fastest of all - about 10x faster than `filtration`, so it looks like it's simd-d!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xt::filter` appears be a view, which are (currently) not super efficient in *xtensor*. I would use `xt::where`. It might result in a temporary though, which may of may not be the case in *NumPy*. Since I don't know the details on the the temporary let's do at least some timing:

### 1. NumPy indexing:

```py
import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime

a = np.random.random([1000000])
start = datetime.now()
a[a > 0.5] = 1.0
stop = datetime.now()
print((stop - start).microseconds)
```

On my system around 5000 microseconds.

### 2. NumPy where

```py
import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime

a = np.random.random([1000000])
start = datetime.now()
a = np.where(a > 0.5, 1.0, a)
stop = datetime.now()
print((stop - start).microseconds)
```

On my system about 2500 microseconds.

### 3. xtensor where

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <xtensor.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    xt::xtensor<double, 1> a = xt::random::rand<double>({1000000});

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();    
    a = xt::where(a > 0.5, 1.0, a);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << duration.count() << endl;
}
```

On my system between 2500 and 5000 microseconds (much more distributed than for NumPy) with *xsimd*, and about twice as long without *xsimd*.

### 4. xtensor filter

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <xtensor.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    xt::xtensor<double, 1> a = xt::random::rand<double>({1000000});

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();    
    xt::filter(a, a > 0.5) = 1.0;
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << duration.count() << endl;
}
```

On my system about 30000 microsconds with and without *xsimd*.

### Compilation

I use

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(Run)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

find_package(xtensor REQUIRED)
find_package(xsimd REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} xtensor xtensor::optimize xtensor::use_xsimd)
```

without *xsimd* I omit the last line.

### Rosetta / native

I am running Mac's M1. The timings listed are on Rosetta (i.e. `x86`). For native build the timings are:

1. 4500 microseconds.
2. 1500 microseconds.
3. 2000 microseconds with and without *xsimd* (I think *xsimd* simply doesn't yet work on that chip!).
4. 15000 microseconds.